# How can I count the number of unique values in a column for each unique value of a different variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, summarize

I have the following dataframe:

```
No Name Fruit Country
1  Tom  Pear  France
2  Tom  Pear  France
3  Tom  Pear  Poland
4  Bob  Kiwi  Poland
5  Bob  Pear  France
6  Ann  Pear  France
7  Ann  Pear  Poland
8  Dod  Pear  Poland
7  Dod  Plum  Poland
8  Dod  Plum  Poland
9  Dod  Pear  Germany
10 Dod  Kiwi  Estonia
```

How can I, for each unique name, count how many unique values there are in the fruit column and then add this number as a column to the dataframe?

The output I would like to get is this:

```
 No Name Fruit Country Unique
1  Tom  Pear  France   1
2  Tom  Pear  France   1
3  Tom  Pear  Poland   1
4  Bob  Kiwi  Poland   2
5  Bob  Pear  France   2
6  Ann  Pear  France   1
7  Ann  Pear  Poland   1
8  Dod  Pear  Poland   3
7  Dod  Plum  Poland   3
8  Dod  Plum  Poland   3
9  Dod  Pear  Germany  3
10 Dod  Kiwi  Estonia  3
```

I tried

```
df %>%
group_by(Name, Fruit) %>%
mutate(unique = n()) %>%
ungroup()
```

But the above does not work the way I wanted it to.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. The way you have shared your data is reproducible but takes awhile to work with. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg. You can also simply create your own toy dataset that resembles this one so its easier for others to help you.

Comment: Use `n_distinct(Fruit)` instead of `n()` in your attempt above.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento - **and** don't group by `Fruit`

Comment: @thelatemail - whoops, yes indeed.

Comment: Yeah I missed that the first go around. I learned something today haha

Comment: Thank you everyone. @Shawn Hemelstrang I will use the function you suggested from now on so that my questions are easier to work with. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No prob. This is usually where people get referenced to go on providing a minimally reproducible dataset if you want more info on what constitutes as "good" for sharing:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your intent was just grouping by name and fruit, but its better to use `mutate` here. You also wouldn't use `ungroup` after unless you were doing manipulations to the data after:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Name,
           Fruit) %>% 
  mutate(Name.Fruit.Unique = n())
```

Which gives you this. You can see for example Tom and Pear show up three times, and it is listed so in the data frame:

```
      No Name  Fruit Country Name.Fruit.Unique
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>               <int>
 1     1 Tom   Pear  France                  3
 2     2 Tom   Pear  France                  3
 3     3 Tom   Pear  Poland                  3
 4     4 Bob   Kiwi  Poland                  1
 5     5 Bob   Pear  France                  1
 6     6 Ann   Pear  France                  2
 7     7 Ann   Pear  Poland                  2
 8     8 Dod   Pear  Poland                  2
 9     7 Dod   Plum  Poland                  2
10     8 Dod   Plum  Poland                  2
11     9 Dod   Pear  Germany                 2
12    10 Dod   Kiwi  Estonia                 1
```

#### Edit

It looks like I misinterpreted your question. For unique values grouped by name and then counting the unique number of fruits per person, this may be a better option:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(Count = n_distinct(Fruit))
```

Which gives you this:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 5
# Groups:   Name [4]
      No Name  Fruit Country Count
   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <int>
 1     1 Tom   Pear  France      1
 2     2 Tom   Pear  France      1
 3     3 Tom   Pear  Poland      1
 4     4 Bob   Kiwi  Poland      2
 5     5 Bob   Pear  France      2
 6     6 Ann   Pear  France      1
 7     7 Ann   Pear  Poland      1
 8     8 Dod   Pear  Poland      3
 9     7 Dod   Plum  Poland      3
10     8 Dod   Plum  Poland      3
11     9 Dod   Pear  Germany     3
12    10 Dod   Kiwi  Estonia     3
```

Comment: My intention was to first group by name, and then for each name find the number of unique values of the fruit variable. Your code outputs 3 for Name == Tom, rather than the value that I have been trying to get, which is 1 (For  Name == Tom, there is only a single unique Fruit).

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No prob! Glad to help.